# Tika returning empty string when deploying on wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, apache-tika

I am using tika-parsers as part of a web application

```
<groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
<artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
<version>1.11</version>
```

and had problems deploying it on wildyfly (8.2.1 and 10.0.0.RC4).
This was [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414611/tika-parsers-deployment-issue-on-wildfly/34418949?noredirect=1) by adding a jboss-all.xml containing:

```
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <weld xmlns="urn:jboss:weld:1.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
</jboss>
```

But now **tika returns empty Strings** for e.g. **pdf or ms office files**. I assume it is falling back to the EmptyParser. Text files seem to work.

This is my simple test code that works correctly when being run as a junit test.

```
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(9000000);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(entry.getValue(), handler, metadata);
String s = handler.toString();
```

Comment: Did you try following the [Apache Tika Troubleshooting guide for "No Content"](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika#No_Content_Extracted)? How far did you get through that?

Comment: It is showing the correct version ("Apache Tika 1.11") and detects the mimetype of my files correctly but still uses the org.apache.tika.parser.EmptyParser for e.g. pdf and doc.

Comment: What about the parser checks - did they show you as having all the parsers you'd expect as available?

Comment: Multiple parsers show including those i expected, but still the EmptyParser is chosen when testing. The only strange thing i found is, that every parsers is listed twice while iterating...

Comment: I got it. Seems the way i iterated through my streams did not work correctly. Thanks for your help though!