# Tika-Parsers error after adding dependency to pom.xml

Tags: maven, java-ee-7, apache-tika, wildfly-10

I have just added tika-parsers dependency into my pom.xml file.
After that, I can't run my project. I have this error everytime :

```
**15:30:07,072 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."scdob-1.0.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."project-1.0.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service**
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
**Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000071: Managed bean with a parameterized bean class must be @Dependent: class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.XPathProvider**
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:208)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractBean.java:107)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(ManagedBean.java:122)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:136)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:127)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

The dependency I have added is

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

What am I done wrong ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can just add or edit this dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Or see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418949/3997419