# Managed bean with a parameterized bean class must be @Dependent: class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider

Tags: java, spring, cdi, apache-tika, wildfly-10

After adding **tika parser** in my application I am getting the following error in my Spring Application. I am  running the application on `wildfly 10.1.1 final`.

```
11:11:30,371 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MyApp.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000071: Managed bean with a parameterized bean class must be @Dependent: class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.AbstractCachingMessageProvider
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkType(ManagedBean.java:208)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(AbstractBean.java:107)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initializeAfterBeanDiscovery(ManagedBean.java:122)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:136)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$AfterBeanDiscoveryInitializerFactory.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:127)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

As per the solutions previously given I have included the following files in my application:

1. `jboss-all.xml` - Location is (`src/main/resources/META-INF/`)
2. `beans.xml` - Location is (`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`)

The contents are as follows :

**beans.xml**

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"   version="2.5"
    bean-discovery-mode="annotated">   
</beans>
```

**jboss-all.xml**

```
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <weld xmlns="urn:jboss:weld:1.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
</jboss>
```

Please let me know if anything else to be done for the fix . I am still getting the same exception as mentioned above .

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Spring app deploy exception on wildfly 12.0.0.Final

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000071: Managed bean with a parameterized bean class must be @Dependent: class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.DataSourceProvider
```

Problem dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Solution help me fixed exception is rename in web.xml contextConfigLocation
`<param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>` deploy exception
`<param-value>WEB-INF/application.xml</param-value>` deploy success

Comment: this worked perfectly on WildFly 23.0.0 as well, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418949

You should create a jboss-all.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <weld xmlns="urn:jboss:weld:1.0" require-bean-descriptor="true"/>
</jboss>
```

and place it under webapp/META-INF.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a spring app, you probably want to just turn off CDI.  In which case your `beans.xml` should be:

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd" bean-discovery-mode="none">
</beans>
```

Comment: I have tried this too .. But still the same issue .